# Which r in perpetuity formula to pricing a business?

Tags: price, price-theory

I am trying to guess a price to sell my small business. I don't understand a thing in the [perpetuity formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetuity). Which is the correct rate I have to put on it?

Answer (score 1):

In the equity markets, the P/E is usually somewhere around 15.  The P/E can be viewed as the inverse of the rate of a perpetuity.

Since the average is 15, and the E/P of that would be 6.7%, `r` should be 6.7% on average.

If your business is growing, the growth rate can be incorporated like so:

```
p / ( r_g - g )
r = r_g - g
```

As you can see, a high `g` would make the price negative, in essence the seller should actually pay someone to take the business, but in reality, `r` is determined from the `p` and an estimated `g`.

For a business of any growth rate, it's best to compare the multiple to the market, so for the average business in the market with your business's growth rate and industry, that P/E would be best applied to your company's income.